# Should Player inherit or own a Level?

Tags: python, inheritance, relationship, class-hierarchy

I've been trying to learn OOP for the last few weeks as much as I can, and I've learned alot, but I'm not certain of this one, what should my class hierarchy look like?

Imagine two classes, here's a `Level`-class:

```
class Level(object):
    def __init__(self, level, exp):
        self.level = level
        self.exp = exp

    @property
    def required_exp(self, level=None):
        return 80 + 40 * (level or self.level)

    def add_exp(self, exp):
        self.exp += exp
        while self.exp >= self.required_exp:
            self.exp -= self.required_exp
            self.level += 1
```

Obviously it has some other methods too, but that's the basic idea.

Now the second class is called `Player`. It has some attributes, such as: `name`, `health`, `level`, `experience points`, `damage`, etc.

What I've learned so far (someone on SO said this) is to ask myself a question when I'm not sure whether to use inheritance (`is-a`-relationship) or attribute (`has-a`-relationship).
The question would be: *Is Player a Level, or does Player have a Level?*

Well... It's neither.
Player certainly is not a level, that I'm sure of.
And Player has it's level, but the level is not equal to `Level` class.
Instead Player has level and experience points, which are both attributes of `Level` class. You can also add experience points to Player, so it would make sense to inherit it from `Level`.

As a sidenote, the namings don't really make any sense to me either. It would make sense to have something like: `Level.increase(self)` to increase a Level by one.
However, for player it would make more sense to call `Player.level_up(self)`, as used in most (all?) rpg games.
Calling `Player.increase(self)` doesn't really make any sense, you can't increase `Player` by one, you're increasing it's level by one.
Then again, calling `Level.level_up(self)` doesn't make that much sense either...

So, I think that I should use `Level` as if it was an interface and inherit `Player` (and other subclasses) from it, but I'm not certain so I decided to ask you, since I'm here to learn anyways.
What should I do? What would be the most proper way to use `Level` with `Player`?

Comment: Sounds like Player-Level is a classic "has-a" relationship in this case. You said, "And Player has it's level, but the level is not equal to Level class." What does that mean, exactly?

Comment: @Santa `Level`-class already has an attribute called `level`. This `level` attribute is the one `Player` should have too, it's simply an integer to tell which level our player is at. `Player` also has experience points (exp) which is also an attribute of `Level`. This is why it'd make sense to inherit Player from Level, else we'd be calling `Player.level.level` to get the actual numeric value of our player's level.

Comment: Indeed, player.level.level is a bit awkward.  One would expect that level should just be an integer, not a full fledged class.  Where is this code for "level" written and can you change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I'm the one who told you to ask yourself the question: *"Is class A a class B, or does class A have a class B?"*, so I feel like I have to answer this question.

I'm not 100% sure of what your level actually does, but I'm assuming it's one similar to the one used in Pokemon, World of Warcraft, League of Legends, and thousands of other games.
If so, you've already gone wrong with your `Level`-class, it shouldn't be like that.

You're right on one thing for sure;
*"Player certainly is not a level"*
As others have already mentioned, you should just go with *has-a* relationship.
Player does have level, we both know that.
However, you're telling me player doesn't have an attribute of type `Level`, but rather an integer `level`-attribute to hold the numeric value of your `Level`-class.

This should already ring some bells, but here's a tip: It's the same as having a `Name`-class that has a `string`-type attribute called `name` inside it.

So the answer is:
`Name` class should already be a string itself, it should inherit from `string`, instead of having a `string` attribute inside it to hold its value.
The same applies for your `Level`, it's already an integer itself so inherit it from `int`, then add `exp` and its methods.

Now you can use `player.level` to return the integer value of player's level.
And to get the `exp`, you "have to" use `player.level.exp`.
I quoted the "have to", since even though it might sound weird, `exp` IS an attribute of level's.
It's basically the same as a decimal point for a number, makes sense?

Also, calling something like `player.level.increase()` makes much more sense now.
Although, it's already an integer value, why not just do `player.level += 1`?
And if you need some advanced stuff inside the addition, you could just override the `Level.__add__(self, value)` method.
I can't think of a single reason why wouldn't you need this though? (not now that you've already made `required_exp` a property)

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, I was just stuck with the is-a and has-a relationships neither fitting well and didn't realize the problem was in my class :) I'm still not too comfty with `exp` not being an attribute of player's, but it fits when ever I think of it as a decimal number, thanks for that too. And I'm using `player.level.increase()` to increase player's skill points (you get one for each level) as his levels increase, but I just realized that I should instead use it to raise an event `level_up` and subscribe player's `add_skill_point` to it... :)

Comment: @SkamahOne Glad to help anyone who's actually willing to learn :) Good thinking with the event, although I'd name them way different. `Level.level_up` event wouldn't really make any more sense than `Level.level_up` method, as you mentioned in your question. Rather call it `Level.increase`, since that's the event happening, Level increases. Now this is optional, but instead of subscribing `add_skill_point`, I'd create a new method `Player.on_level_up()` and subscribe it to `Level.increase`. But that depends on your event system and your personal preferrance.

Answer (score 3):

Player has-a level.  As you said, "Player certainly is not a level."  When you use inheritance, it implies that the player is a subtype of level (which of course doesn't make sense at all).

This is a clear has-a relationship.  Interact with the level with methods such as `player1.levelup()` or `player1.addxp()` which refer to the level attribute.

Comment: When questioning about object-oriented style, also, think of what design makes sense for your application in the abstract -- before paying attention to how the existing resources fit together.  First, see that player clearly should have-a level, then figure out how to fit the pieces appropriately.  As in the zen of python; "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: Even tho I didn't accept you, I totally gave you an upvote for the good answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are already sure Player is not a Level, then inheritance is not the correct mechanism. Inheritance works for relationships like "A car is a vehicle, and a motorbike is a vehicle", so in that situation both Car and Motorbike are subclasses of Vehicle.

However, this relationship doesn't fit either with a real [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), in the sense that Level shouldn't be represented as another class with its own functionality. It is true that a player *has a* level, but as you point out, `player.level_up()` and `player.add_experience()` is more clear than calling these methods with a `level` object. That is because the interaction with the player's level makes sense through its methods, not with `player.level.level`. Then you should consider moving the functionality of your Level class to Player:

[image: Class diagram]

Answer (score 0):

The player definitely isn't a level but he has a level. I don't see your problem with using the level class defined above in the player class, as it keeps track of all the important information for the player that is a part of a level.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping track of both the level and the *additional* experience with respect to that level, you could simply keep track of the *total experience*.

From the total experience you can derive the level and the amount of experience needed to reach the next level, or any other such quantity you might be interested in.

For example,

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, exp=0):
        self.exp = exp
    @property
    def level(self):
        if self.exp<80:
            return 0
        return (self.exp-80)//40 + 1
    @property
    def required_exp(self):
        return 80 + 40*self.level
    def add_exp(self, exp):
        self.exp += exp


ringo = Player(exp=80)
print(ringo.level)
# 1

print(ringo.required_exp)
# 120
```