# Inheriting from an immutable types?

Tags: inheritance, lua, metatable

I just [answered a Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490290/should-player-inherit-or-own-a-level/16490575#16490575) which "required" inheriting a class from `int` (immutable type in Python).
I've been doing some Lua lately and as I answered the question, I thought; "How is this done in Lua?"

So, can I inherit a class from an immutable type in Lua? If yes, how?
And if inheriting from a class such as integer is not possible, is there an other way to implement behavior similar to the one in my answer on the Python question?

As a sidenote, I'm still having quite a lot of trouble understanding Lua's metatables.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Lua does not have an object oriented policy. From PiL2, chapter 15:

> Usually, Lua does not set policies. Instead, Lua provides mechanisms
>      that are powerful enough for groups of developers to implement the
>    policies that best suit them.

There are many approaches to object oriented programming in Lua.

In Lua, `int` is not a class. It is not even a type (Lua uses C `double` to represent numbers by default).

That said, it is possible to use a `metatable` to make a `table` immutable. So, if you are using `table`s to implement your classes (or prototypes), then you can certainly inherit from them. You can also use `userdata` for your class or prototype, and its (im)mutability would be established by your C library that creates the `userdata`.

You can read about immutable `table`s in [PiL 13.4.5](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.5.html). You should read chapters 13 and 16 to learn about metatables and OOP in Lua.

If you want further examples, the [LOOP](http://loop.luaforge.net/) package implements several OOP models.